# How can I output the points that are colinear?

Tags: java

THE PROBLEM: Write a program that reads N points in a plane and outputs any group of four or more colinear points
What I did: I calculated the slope of every 2 points and then put them in a hashmap to see which one is the max.
What I need to do: I need to output the points that are colinear from the initial 2D array. I found the number of points that are colinear with the hashmap.
import java.util.*;

```
public class app {

public static int maxPoints(int[][] points) {

    int ans = 1;
    int n = points.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int OLP = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (points[i][0] == points[j][0] && points[i][1] == points[j][1]) {
                OLP++;
                continue;
            }
            int dy = points[j][1] - points[i][1];
            int dx = points[j][0] - points[i][0];
            int g = gcd(Math.abs(dy), Math.abs(dx));
            int num = dy / g;
            int deno = dx / g;
            if (num == 0)
                deno = 1;
            if (deno == 0)
                num = 1;
            if ((num < 0 && deno < 0) || deno < 0) {
                num *= -1;
                deno *= -1;
            }
            map.put(createString(deno, num), map.getOrDefault(createString(deno, num), 0) + 1);
            max = Math.max(max, map.get(createString(deno, num)));
            
        }

        ans = Math.max(ans, 1 + OLP + max);
    }
    return ans;
}

public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    int max = Math.max(a, b);
    int min = Math.min(a, b);
    return gcd(max % min, min);
}

public static String createString(int a, int b) {
    return Integer.toString(a) + " " + Integer.toString(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] points = { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, { 5, 4 } };
    System.out.println("max Points are: " + maxPoints(points));
}}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the math, e.g., how to determine if a point is on a line? Or something else?

Comment: @DaveNewton I actually figured out the math I just want to output the points from the array because in this code I just got the max number of the points that are in line.

Comment: Please provide the *exact* issue you're encountering. Without a clear question, you're never going to get a clear answer. https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @Jesse I added more details is it clear enough now ?

Comment: @AzizMlayel I'm still having a hard time trying to figure out the problem you are running into. I get that you're trying to output the actual points, but what roadblock are you running into when trying to accomplish this yourself? What have you tried to try and accomplish this?

Comment: You currently have a map local to the `maxPoints` function. You can output the map within that function, or put the map somewhere else. One thing to note is that `maxPoints` is currently responsible for two different things, which is suspicious.